# Split a dictionary data into 2 parts and store into variable

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, training-data

So I have this cosine similarity metric dictionary data with me that is stored in the variable 'similarity'. [PIC of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfcMU.png) .
May I know how can I split this data into portion of 70 and 30 precents. I want to split this data into two parts and store those two in a variable most preferably the split can be 7:3 division

The reason i have asking this is I have an accuracy algorithm that gives the accuracy of that data but the problem is that i used same data for training as well as testing as you can see in the code so I receive 100% acc obviously as my training and testing data is same. so wanted to split data into 70 30 percent such  training is 70 and testing is 30.

```
print(similarity)


train_r =  np.array(similarity)
test_r =  np.array(similarity)

train_c = train_r[:,10]
test_c = test_r[:,10]

a = train_c
b = test_c

cos_sim = (dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))) * 100
print(cos_sim)
```

It would be really grateful if I can get the answer. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
split_rate = 0.7
split_idx = int(len(similarity)*split_rate)
train_r =  np.array(similarity)[:split_idx] 
test_r =  np.array(similarity)[split_idx:]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for being late but i am actaully getting an error ```TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method``` when i put in that code..For reference.this is the code i am running..                   ```split_rate = 0.7
    split_idx = len(similarity)*split_rate
    
    train_r = np.array(similarity)[:split_idx]
    test_r =  np.array(similarity)[split_idx:]
    
    train_c = train_r[:,10]
    test_c = test_r[:,10]
    
    a = train_c
    b = test_c
    
    cos_sim = (dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))) * 100
    print(cos_sim)```

Comment: I added a int() call, it should be ok now I guess.

Comment: Helllo thanks ive changed it as per above but i now receive this error....``` cos_sim = (dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))) * 100
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in dot
ValueError: shapes (8,) and (4,) not aligned: 8 (dim 0) != 4 (dim 0)```

Comment: Well, the dot product of two vectors is only defined if they have the same length. (I don't get why you do a dot() but never mind). Take a split_rate = 0.5 (and a even similarity length) or change the dot() function call. What are the shapes of a and b ?

Comment: oh i put 0.5 and it worked. But need 0.7 actually for training but it gives error..trying to solve that atm

Comment: Are you sure you have to take the dot product between a and b ?

Comment: i am a bit confused about that part as i got it from github but cant understand how it works..may i know any alternative to this that may solve my problem?

Comment: Well... First, is your similarity a 2D array or not ? It should be I guess. Then you would compute the cos_sim for every entry pair.

Comment: entry pair as in?

Comment: I mean if similarity is a 2D vector you can compute the cos_sim for a[0] and b[0], a[0] and b[1], ... a[1] and b[0], a[1] andb[1] ... This is true if similarity is a 2D vector because then a[0] is a 1D vector

Comment: Thank you..it started working now..i had to do some adjustments in the dot product and train_c = train_r[:,10]
test_c = test_r[:,10].